Is there a way to create a bootstrapped beta calibration function to use on new data?
I have created ML classification models that are now to be evaluated on a different population for external validation (n=5000, event rates between n=400 and n=1200 for different outcomes under study).
The models have acceptable discrimination in the external validation but are less well calibrated, probably because the event rates in the external validation data is lower than in the development data.
So I want to create a calibration model so that new predictions can be made using the original ML models but calibrated to this population. The goal is to enter data for a single case in a shiny app and get an estimation that is calibrated for the population in question.
My problems are the following:
-using linear regression based models I get some negative values, and my understanding is that an estimated probability should never have a negative value.
-the "bootstrapped isotonic regression" in the "probably" package seemed reasonable but cannot create a function to use on new data as far as I understand.
-betacalibration using the "betacal" package is enticing and can create a function but is it possible to train this function in a bootstrapped manner as in the "bootstrapped isotonic regression"? Otherwise I get a very overfitted calibration model. Furthermore, if I need to make partitions to the data I will get a weaker model and I would like to adhere to the recommendations by Harrell, Steyerberg et al to avoid making splits and use rather use crossvalidation or bootstrapping.
Is there a way to train the beta cal model in a bootstrapped manner?
